# Email-Ext Jenkins Plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, email-ext

Using this plugin to send email notifications after all builds complete. Even if I set the trigger to "Always" under the advanced options of the Editable Email Notification plugin, the email is not always sent. It's sent on all failures and the first success after those failures. But not on all build executions. Thoughts on what I may be doing wrong here?

Comment: Is your server allowed to send outgoing mail? Ask your system administrator to verify that, please.

Comment: Hi Stephen. Thank you for the reply :)

Yes, emails are permitted. I have gotten email notifications to work when the build fails. However, I've set the trigger to always email regardless if the build fails or succeeds. That trigger seems to not work properly.

Comment: Anyone else? Would really like to know if this plugin is just broken

Answer (score 0):

Add all email address in “Project Recipient List“

Click on “Advance Settings”, Go to "Trigger" and Check “Send To” option for “Always”, If it's not “Recipient List”, then Add “Recipient List” and save your job.